# How to break a string into an array

Tags: java, parsing, text

I have a problem with parsing text, i have transcript of interview and i have a tag which channel is talking (ch1,ch2). And i need to break it into array and i could to search in which channel someone tells specific word.

For example this is a part of interview

```
<ch1>Hello</ch1> <ch2>Hello</ch2> <ch1>How are you</ch1><ch2>I'm fine</ch2>
```

This is a string

```
String text = "<ch1>Hello</ch1> <ch2>Hello</ch2> <ch2>How are you</ch2>
<ch2>I'm fine</ch2>";
```

And i want output

```
 String output[] = {<ch1>Hello</ch1>,<ch2>Hello</ch2>,....}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String dialogue = "<ch1>Hello</ch1> <ch2>Hello</ch2> <ch1>How are you</ch1><ch2>I'm fine</ch2>";
String[] statements = dialogue.split("(?<=</ch[12]>)\\s*(?=<ch[12]>)");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(statements));
```

Output:

```
[<ch1>Hello</ch1>, <ch2>Hello</ch2>, <ch1>How are you</ch1>, <ch2>I'm fine</ch2>]
```

It's a bit hard to read due to the many `<` and `>`, but the pattern is like this:

```
split("(?<=endOfLastPart)inBetween(?=startOfNextPart)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.split("<ch").join("-<ch").split("-").
```

Can be any string instead of "-" which can be used.

Comment: What if there are other `-` in the text? Better use a _much_ more unique separator character (or character sequence).